# What does it mean when a player in GTA V Online has a flag as their icon on the map?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

What does it mean when a player in GTA V Online has a flag as their player icon instead of the normal blip? Does it mean they are paused or that they have lost connection?

Comment: Can you provide a snapshot?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tested this a few days ago with a friend, because I was also curious. Here's what I found out:
When a player is displayed as a "flag icon" instead of a dot icon it means they are currently on the world map or in the menu. When you go near a player when they have said "flag icon" it will also say "Paused" next to their name.
All in all, it indicates to other players that you are an easy target.